# How Do You Get Variable Between Final Dash and File Extension Using Mod_Rewrite?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have had great success with mod_rewrite rules, but have come across a snag.

Am wanting to get everything between the final dash and file extension. Eg. In the following example URL of domain.com/folder/sub-folder/product-title-that-may-contain-dashes-and-numbers-347.html I wish to get the "347" characters.

This is the item ID, that is being passed to the item.php page. (At the moment it is currently ONLY an integer, but I am looking to change it so that it can be alphanumeric eg. 347b)

I am using the following code.

```
RewriteRule  ^folder/.*/.*-([0-9]+)\.html$   item.php?item-id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This works fine for most URLs, but when the characters after the final slash start with a number, it generates an error ("This webpage has a redirect loop", "Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"). It is fine if there is a number anywhere else within the characters after the final slash, just NOT at the start.

Any ideas?

PS. Please be kind. This is my first post/question on a forum, ever. So please excuse if I have not followed any applicable rules/etiquette/formalities/etc that would be deemed as common knowledge to standard users. (I normally find answers to problems via Google searches, but can't seem to locate one for this specific example.)

Comment: Actually, just found that my error lay in the file where the variables were being passed.

As I had recently changed the format of the URL's, I used a PHP 301 redirect within the PHP file to redirect files in the format:

domain.com/folder/sub-folder/product-title-that-may-contain-dashes-and-numbers/347

to the new format:

domain.com/folder/sub-folder/product-title-that-may-contain-dashes-and-numbers-347.html

And there was an error within my PHP code.

PS. Is the etiquette to delete this post?

Comment: Don't worry, that's a quite well-written first question anyway. Post your resolution as answer (tomorrow) if you feel it might help others. But btw, the `RewriteLog` is often useful for debugging such issues.

Comment: Thanks.

In my PHP file I was using:

    $lastNumbers = substr($currentURL, strrpos($currentURL, '/' )+1 );

to get the characters after the final slash (eg. the "347" component of domain.com/folder-sub-folder/product-name/347) in the old URL format.

But used poor code which was trying to redirect old format URL's to new format URL's for anything which started with a number directly after the final slash (as per original qu).

Updated it to use basic:

    if (is_numeric($lastNumbers)) {
     header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
     header("Location: $redirectURL");
     exit();
    }

Answer (score 0):

FYI, answer to this question (and real issue) posted below in entirety, in case it may help anyone else.

The mod_rewrite code referenced was actually correct. It was found that the error lay in the file where the variables were being passed.

As I had recently changed the format of the URL's, I used a PHP 301 redirect within the PHP file to redirect files in the format:

domain.com/folder/sub-folder/product-title-that-may-contain-dashes-and-numbers/3‌​47

to the new format:

domain.com/folder/sub-folder/product-title-that-may-contain-dashes-and-numbers-3‌​47.html

And there was an error within the PHP code.

In the PHP file I was using:

```
$lastNumbers = substr($currentURL, strrpos($currentURL, '/' )+1 );
```

to get the characters after the final slash (eg. the "347" component of domain.com/folder-sub-folder/product-name/347) in the old URL format.

But used poor code which was trying to redirect old format URL's to new format URL's for anything which started with a number directly after the final slash (as per original question).

Updated it to use basic:

```
if (is_numeric($lastNumbers)) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: $redirectURL");
    exit();
}
```